# SQL Query Where Between two date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried get all records between after 00:00 and now time

E.g  Between 21.02.2014 00:01 and 21.02.2014 10:41(now time)

```
 Select * from TableName Where Time >=???     and Time < Getdate()
```

Comment: Use Where Time between ??? and Getdate()

Comment: Try: select * from table where time >= '21.02.2014 00:01' and time < '21.02.2014 10:41';

Comment: do you have a question? there's nothing wrong with your syntax

Comment: @user3107343 If it is solved, please post the answer and accept it in case the solution is already not provided below. It saves time and efforts for others.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from TableName Where Time between ??? and Getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select * from TableName Where DateDiff(day,TimeColumn,getdate()) 

    between 0 and 0
```

Comment: you can use `DateDiff(day,TimeColumn,getdate()) = 0`

Comment: The problem with `datediff` is that it will make it impossible for the optimizer to use any existing index on the `TimeColumn`. As a good heuristic/rule-of-thumb, avoid using function over a column.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL 2008 or later, you can do something like the ff:

```
select * 
from tablename 
where cast([Time] as date) = getdate() 
    and cast([Time] as time) >= '10:41'
```

This isn't going to be super performant as the `cast` makes the predicate non-SARGable. If this is something that you envision doing frequently, you can add persisted computed columns to your table that do the casts for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from TableName Where Time between cast(GETDATE() as DATE) and Getdate()
```